# Como colocar um script .php de paginaçao no meu website?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Eu já construí um site, mas estou tendo problema com o sistema de paginação. Eu não sei mexer com php, eu achei uns vídeos no youtube e consegui um script de paginação em php. Agora eu preciso colocar esse script dentro do meu site.

Eu acho que pra isso eu preciso linkar o arquivo .php dentro do meu arquivo .html tipo quando o cara usa o comando 'link' no html. Mas não sei como se faz.

Esse é o script de paginaçao em php:

A parte de conexao de banco de dados esta nas 15 primeiras linhas do script q eu colei.

```
<?php
$servername = "Localhost";
$username = "id6683339_unknn";
$password = "****";

// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect("mysql#.000webhost.com","id6683339_unknn","****") or die(mysql_error());

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    `insira o código aqui`die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

<?php
    $maxlinks = 4;
    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
    $maximo = 12;
    $inicio = (($maximo * $pagina) - $maximo);

    $selecao = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $inicio, $maximo");
    $selecao->execute();
    while($posts = $selecao->fetchObject()):
?>
    <li><?php echo utf8_encode($posts->titulo);?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>

<?php
    $seleciona_2 = $pdp->prepare("SELECT * FROM `posts`");
    $seleciona_2->execute();
    $total = $seleciona_2->rowCount();
    $total_paginas = ceil($total/$maximo);

if($total > $maximo){

    echo '<a href="?pagina=1">Primeira pagina</a>';
    for($i = $pagina - $maxlinks; $i <= $pagina -1; $i++){
        if($i >= 1){
            echo '<a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
        }
    }
    echo '<span>'.$pagina.'</span>';
    for($i = $pagina +1; $i <= $pagina + $maxlinks; $i++){
        if($i <= $total_paginas){
            echo '<a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
        }
    }
    echo '<a href="?pagina='.$total_paginas.'">Ultima pagina</a>';
}
?>
```

Eu não sei se o script de paginação esta certo, mas a questão é q eu não sei como colocar ele no meu website. Eu hospedei o meu site no 000webhost.com, descobri q pra mexer com arquivo .php é preciso usar o phpmyadmin, o 000webhost usa o banco de dados do phpmyadmin mas eu não sei mexer nele, comecei a aprender programação faz umas 2 semanas.

No phpmyadmin tem 3 pastas, eu nao sei se é preciso colocar o arquivo .php dentro de uma pasta expecifica.[image: phpmyadmin]

Seria mais fácil eu usar o servidor apache, mas no momento ele não esta funcionando no meu pc, preciso formatá-lo.

Comment: coloca assim no local onde vai ficar no html `include "nome_do_arquivo_de_paginacao.php;"`

Comment: Seu arquivo HTML tem que ter a extensão php  para funcionar o que o @WeesSmith disse. Tipo `home.html` tem que ser `home.php`

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário @AndreiCoelho

Comment: Antes de fazer isso sugiro aprender php, e pelo menos ter uma noção de banco de dados, fazer uma paginação funcional é algo um pouco avançado pra quem começou a programar a 2 semanas

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Tem toda razão, e eu vou fazer  exatamente isso.

Comment: Amigo, se você precisa fazer paginação em php/html, não complique sua vida fazendo a paginação toda na mão, aconselharia, primeiramente fazer o que o @GuilhermeCostamilam falou, estude php/banco de dados. Outra coisa, essa paginação pode ser usada datagrid. Bem mais simples, mais bonito e mais eficiente

https://www.pontikis.net/labs/bs_grid/demo/

Comment: @gabrielfalieri datagrid com certeza é mais simples, bonito é opinião, mas não é mais eficiente, imagina que a paginação é de 1000 linhas do banco, ter que carregar tudo isso pra no final o usuário ir no máximo até a página dois, até pode ser considerado eficiente em relação a agilidade no desenvolvimento, mas não na performance do sistema

Comment: Cara, você já viu funcionamento do datagrid? Que ele envia a requisição com um order by 10 a 19, 20 a 29 e assim vai.. nunca os 1000 linhas de banco de uma vez

Comment: Não vi isso, mas de qualquer jeito tem que fazer as alterações no php, validar esses `LIMIT` e `OFFSET` para não ter SQL Injection. No final da mais trabalho. Obs: `ORDER BY` não faz paginação

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente vamos definir algumas coisas, o phpMyAdmin é a sua interface para gerenciamento do banco de dados, local onde é feito o armazenamento dos registros que serão recuperados em algum momento, como textos e etc. Seu arquivo .php, devera ficar armazenado em sua hospedagem, junto dos outros arquivos .html e etc... Ele fará a comunicação com seu banco de dados para recuperar as informações a serem paginadas.
 Para que sua paginação possa funcionar, será necessário incorporar o php em sua página html, utilizando include ou require, leia mais sobre eles:

Include: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php

Require: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.require.php

Exemplo com include:

```
include 'diretorio1/diretorio2/paginacao.php';
```

Mas pelo que percebi, apenas esta informação não resolvera seu problema, pois outros conhecimentos precisam ser adquiridos para que essa paginação funcione e seja implementada de forma mais adequada. Acredito que em sua trajetória no aprendizado do php, vera que algumas atitudes devem ser tomadas com relação a este arquivo de paginação, um exemplo seria a extração de sua conexão com banco de dados para um outro arquivo. 
 Não sei qual o objetivo do seu projeto, mas em muitos casos vale a pena utilizar um CMS (Content Manager System), como Joomla ou WordPress, coisas como paginação, seria algo para não se preocupar, MAS isso não quer dizer que você não terá que estudar o funcionamento.

Comment: Pesquisei muito sobre isso e nada, acho melhor eu ir aprender os principios basicos de php. Talvez seja porque eu sou novato mas comparando HTML, JS, CSS, PHP, eu achei php muito dificil. Eu so queria um sistema de paginaçao pra meu site ficar organizado mas tudo bem kk.